# Job Execution And Persistence

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have used jdbcjobstore to persist jobs in database. My Job is being stored successfully but it is not executed. Here comes my quartz.properties file:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MieScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate 
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.threadPool.class =     org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool  
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck= true 
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS      
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SCHEDULER_DB
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user=root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password=user
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections=8
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class =org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin      
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = quartz-config.xml 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
```

I can see records in QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS table but the column TIMES_TRIGGERED value is not updated indicating that the job is not executed. How to get over this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is that the scheduler is actually started. You can check this in the debugger, or you can enable remote JMX access to your Quartz scheduler instance and use jconsole (or any "quartz scheduler gui") to inspect Quartz scheduler's runtime properties including the current state.

Starting the scheduler:

If you are using Spring, the scheduler can be automatically started by setting the Spring SchedulerFactoryBean's autoStartup property to true.

If you are instantiating the scheduler manually, you must not forget to call the start method on the scheduler instance.